# Too many data points in set. Looking for ways to prune

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, statistics

I am gathering data from a website. I estimate to get 10.000 datapoints (time - value) multiplied by seven - over time. That is way to much. Both for storing and plotting it in a real time alike graph (through jQuery flot).
I'm looking for a text dealing with this sort of problems. To be more precise: algorithms, statistical math for finding least significant points (if that would be a good idea), general ideas on dealing with this sort of problem. If a text were available on the net that be great. Reference to a book would do also.

Comment: This seems like more of a math / statistics problem than a programming problem. Try Math Overflow.

Comment: Or not: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34570/mathoverflow-net-how-can-we-get-members-of-this-site-and-the-so-sf-su-sites-to-s

Comment: I'm looking for an algorithm to solve a problem. Providing an open source javaScript solution would do also. This is a real life programming problem to me.

Comment: How granular are the times? 2 per day? 100 per day?

Comment: That would depend on the user. It's an online game. I expect a user to gain stats max 5 times a day.

What I need to do is split the seven stats, giving them their own timeline. Then I expect zero for most and one - five gains on an individual stat. That would double the data I need to store ;(

But this gives you an idea. Also about not needing to store every datapoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the apha beta pruning article on Wikipedia I came up with this idea:
The least significant point is the point where the smallest change took place. In the data array that would be the difference between `arr[i-1]` and `arr[i+1]`. Then it's easy to find `i`:

```
var smallest = 10000; // large to start with
var rememberI = 0;
function prune(arr){
    for(i in arr){
        if(i > 0 && i < arr.length){
            var test = arr[i+1] - arr[i-1];
            if(test < smallest){
                smallest = test;
                rememberI = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return rememberI;
}
```

I haven't tested it yet, but it looks like a promising idea.

Comment: I tested this on another -similar- datastream. It seems to work nice. It has pruned the timeline and now it now starts to prune the recently added datapoints because they are taken close after one another (not much change there).